# Updating a textarea label with the number of characters inside the field itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would you improve and shorten this small piece of code? It basically update a `textarea` label with the number of characters inside the field itself. It saves the original label and restores it when characters count is `0`.

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/274gy/1/) while `sprintf` is from [here](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf).

```
$('#send_sms_content').keyup(function() {

    // The label and characters count of textarea
    var label = $(sprintf('label[for="%s"]', $(this).attr('id'))),
        count = $(this).val().length;

    // Make backup of label original html into "data-original-value" attribute
    if($.type(label.attr('data-original-value')) === 'undefined') {
        label.attr('data-original-value', label.html());
    }

    // When empty textarea then restore the orignal label
    if(count == 0) {
        label.html(label.attr('data-original-value'));
        return;
    }

    // Regular expression to match any digit in the label
    var digit = new RegExp("[0-9]+")

    // If there are no digits in the label append the count
    if(!digit.test(label.html())) {
        label.html(label.html() + ' ' + sprintf('(%s)', count));
    }
    else { // There are digits already, replace with the new count
        label.html(label.html().replace(digit, count));
    }

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a few things I notice, prolly not warranting a "mark as answer" but may help:

1. Cache `$(this)`: `var $this = $(this);` So that you don't keep inefficiently re-wrapping `this`
2. `$(this).attr('id')` - really? You can just use `this.id`, you know.
3. `hasDigit === digit`, so why do you have both? Scrap one of those regexes, the other one is redundant.
4. Cache `label.html()` so that you don't keep grabbing it (which is quite inefficient). Instead: `var labelHtml = label.html()` and then reuse `labelHtml`

Comment: First thank you. I dint' know the thing of `$this.id` and `hasDigit` is a typo. I'll do as you suggested!

Answer (score 3):

You should consider using the `.data()` method of jQuery instead of `.attr()`. Also this:

> ```
> if($.type(label.attr('data-original-value')) === 'undefined') { // Label html backup
>     label.attr('data-original-value', label.html());
> }
> ```

is unnecessarily complicated. It could be simplified to

```
if (!label.data('original-value')) {
    label.data('original-value', label.html());
}
```

---

You could simplify everything even more, if you would add an additional element to your label to use as output, so you don't need to replace and parse the label text.

```
<label for="send_sms_content">My Label<output></output></label>
<textarea id="send_sms_content"></textarea>

$('#send_sms_content').keyup(function() {

    var output = $(sprintf('label[for="%s"] output', this.id)),
        count = $(this).val().length;

    if (count = 0) {
      output.empty();
    } else {
      output.text(sprintf(' (%s)', count));
    }
}
```

---

Finally you can generalize this by setting an attribute on the output element to refer to the element you're are counting the length of:

```
<label for="send_sms_content">My Label<output data-count-selector="#send_sms_content"></output></label>
<textarea id="send_sms_content"></textarea>

$('[data-count-selector]').each(function () {
   var output = $(this);

   // .on() is the preferred way to set event handlers in jQuery 1.7
   // Listen to more events for more flexibility
   $($(this).data('count-selector')).on('keyup change click', function() {
      var count = $(this).val().length;

      if (count = 0) {
        output.empty();
      } else {
        output.text(sprintf(' (%s)', count));
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Good answer. Unfortunately it's not so simple to add `<output>` to label element (i'm using Twig template engine). And AFAIK `<output>` isn't supported in IE, am i right?

Comment: `output` is HTML5, which IE doesn't support unless you use a shim script such as [html5shim](https://code.google.com/p/html5shim/). Or you can just use any other element such as a `span`. I'm currently using Twig too, and it should be no problem adding an element to labels in specific case.